# Button does not disable on change in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this button that will be disabled everytime that the form is invalid

```
<button [disabled]="createForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right button-spinner" tabindex="0" ><span>NEXT</span></button>
```

but it seems like the validation only effect everytime I blur on a form control instead on change.

I also added this on ngOnit and changed the `[disabled]="isNextDisabled"` but it seems that the state will change on change too

```
this.createForm.valueChanges
        .subscribe(formValue => {
                this.isNextDisabled = !this.createForm.valid;
            }
        );
```

The initialization of the form:

```
this.createForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            formText: ['', Validators.required],
            list: ['', Validators.required]
)};
```

Comment: please show the validator

Comment: any error in your console throughout this page from loading to change in any input fields? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I will try to resolve your issue with one example as I did. Follow this you can do.

test.html

```
<form [formGroup]="changePasswordForm" (ngSubmit)="changePassword()">
          <ion-item color="border-text">
            <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Existing Password"
                       formControlName="existing_pass"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item no-lines *ngIf="existingPass.invalid && existingPass.touched">
            <ion-label style="color:#F53D3D" no-margin stacked>Existing Password Required</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
         <div class="buttonClass">
         <button [disabled]="!isReadyToSave" ion-button round color="primary" block
                style="margin-top: 20px !important;">Save
         </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

test.ts

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

changePasswordForm: FormGroup;
isReadyToSave: boolean = false;
constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder,) {

 this.changePasswordForm = formBuilder.group({
    existing_pass: ['', Validators.required]

  });

 this.changePasswordForm.valueChanges.subscribe((v) => {
    this.isReadyToSave = this.chanegPasswordForm.valid;
  });
}
```

Comment: i guess this is the same with my current implementation. the difference is the valueChanges and creation of form. Yours is in the constructor, mine is in `ngOnInit` will that matter?

Comment: No, but try to check it putting it in the constructor. Which angular version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- disable the button -->
<button>
Disable Button
</button>

<!-- enable the button -->
<button>
Enable Button
</button>

<!-- the target button -->
<button disabled="disabled">
I've been clicked {{count}} times.
</button>



follow the link below for getting the detail:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurieatkinson/2016/09/12/using-data-binding-with-angular-2-to-disable-a-button/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by checking your `formGroup` is valid or not with the attribute `[disabled]`, check below for more clarification

**TS:**

```
// method which will create the FormGroup
private createMyForm() {
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
            FormFiled1 : new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)]),
            FormFiled2 : new FormControl('', []),
            FormFiled3 : new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
        });
    }
```

`[Validators.required]` this will make the formfield required, as soon as you dont enter anything into the field the form will invalid
hence you have to check form is valid or not by using below code

**HTML:**

```
// set [disabled] value as true or false to disable or enable the button 
<button type="submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid" (click)="MyFunction()">Submit</button>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1jexl3)

Comment: Yeah. you are right. But it seems that the form will only validated after I click outside the input texts or textareas even though I didn't add `updateOn blur` or something

Answer (score 0):

You can use two operations

```
<button [disabled]='createForm.invalid || isNextDisabled'>Submit</button>
```

And use what you have tried to disable when valueChanges

```
this.createForm.valueChanges.subscribe((v) => {
      this.isNextDisabled = !this.createForm.valid;
 });
```

**Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-disabled-button-on-change)**

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may not need to separately look for `valueChanges`. Here is a code

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="createForm">
    <input formControlName='formText'>
    <input formControlName='list'>

    <button [disabled]="createForm.invalid"
 type="submit"
  class="btn btn-primary pull-right button-spinner"
   tabindex="0" >
   <span>NEXT</span>
   </button>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
   FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators
} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  createForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      formText: ["", Validators.required],
      list: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwxjai)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! but I really have no idea why on my app, it will only validate when I click outside the textarea/input text :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using onchange disables or enables when the focus is out from the input field.

For this you need to use **ngModelChange**, then it will enable/disable the button when you're in the input field.

This method is generally used for only a single input field like confirmation pop with input field for deleting, suspended etc

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Please Confirm</mat-label>
      <input matInput name="value" [(ngModel)]='value' placeholder="Enter {{confirmValue}}" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
        autocomplete="off">
    </mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button class="mat-accent mr-16" (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="confirmDisable">
    <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>Confirm
  </button>
```

TS

```
  confirmDisable: boolean = false;
  value!: string;

  onChange($event: any) {
    this.confirmDisable= this.value === this.confirmValue ? false : true;
  }
  
  onSubmit() {
    //now confirm, we can proceed further
  }
```